# ajax wordpress posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using Wordpress for this design portfolio website: http://onomadesign.com/wordpress/identity-design/shleppers-moving-storage/

Now, on this single.php page, you can see the thumbnails on the right which link to each different post. What I would like to accomplish is that the thumbnail navigation with scrollbar, stays in the same position when people click on one to view a project. Now the whole page refreshes, so that the scrollbar is viewed from the top again. I don't want that.

So, I think I have to 'ajax' some stuff, right? Preferrably using jQuery, because I use that library through the website allready. Can I make that div on the right side with the thumbnails not to refresh while the rest of the page does? Or fetch the single posts so that it 'ajax refreshes'?

I hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance for any help!

Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the whole left side of your page refresh when you click one of the links. This should have been taken into account when you started to design the page, to implement it at this stage can be very hacky to say the least.

Anyways, the simplest solution is this:

- Capture the thumbnail's click event
- Instead of redirecting the browser to the URL it points to, fetch that URL by AJAX
- Get the current side bar in a selection
- Replace the sidebar of the new page with the sidebar of the current page
- Replace the current DOM with the DOM of the new page

This is far from optimal – it is very heavy to modify the DOM in this way and it might result in weird things happening with the rest of the code (cufón not firing, etc) but it's the simplest to implement. It actually does the opposite of what AJAX is supposed to do: this fetches whole content and 'keeps' only on block, whereas normally AJAX is used to fetch only smaller blocks at a time.

To do it *properly*, you would need to have a page which only has the content you need to update, then you'd fetch that content and only replace a part of your page. If that's possible, that would be the way to go.

If you want to try the first method, I can give you the code for that. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that. I stumbled upon this: <a href="http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/fetching-posts-in-wordpress-expressionengine-with-jquery-ajax/"> fetching posts in wordpress</a>. Could I apply this to accomplish what I want?

Another option I was thinking of: somehow make the 'current' thumbnail centre in the scrollbar.. Don't know how hard that is. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I mean http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/fetching-posts-in-wordpress-expressionengine-with-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Actually, the method in the link your posted might work. Are you able to work it out yourself? If you try that method and run into problems, I suggest that you just post a new question. The alternative method you also suggested is possible and actually relatively easy to accomplish - let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: We'll go with the alternative, relatively easy method. And I would really like some help with that, yes:) Thanks a million. Can it be done with pure CSS or does it need some (jQuery) Javascript?

Comment: It requires some jQuery; detecting what link was pressed and adjusting the scroll of the sidebar so that the current link is centered. Could you mark this as accepted (or remove this question) and formulate a new question on that subject as it is fundamentally different than this one?